# Ctrl+Click navigation on Eclipse RSE

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rse

Just wondering if there is any workaround for ctrl+click navigation feature of Eclipse to work on Remote System Explorer (RSE)? I need to modify some Python packages which are hosted on a server and I access them through RSE. It will save me a lot of time if I can get the ctrl+click navigation working!

Comment: You have to add more details in order to get an answert

Comment: I think it is clear enough. Any Eclipse user would know what ctrl+click navigation is. But it is not working if you open a code through RSE plugin. I am asking to see if anyone has a workaround for that!